# In iOS, what happens when a view animation is started while it is already animating?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit

When a view is animated by a gesture recognizer of tapping the main view:

```
-(void) doAnimate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 

                     animations:^{
                         self.circleView.center = CGPointMake(100, 300);
                     }

                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"finished is %i", finished);
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                             self.circleView.center = CGPointMake(250, 300);
                         }];
                     }
     ]; 
}
```

(there is chained animation).  If it is animating and the main view is tapped again, I actually see the completion handler called twice, first with TRUE, and the second time with FALSE.  I thought it was to be called only once, with FALSE? I can't find it in [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1).  Is there a rule for how it works if animation starts when it is already animating?  (I think it apply it is the same view being animated again, and doesn't apply if view2 is animated while view1 is animating?)

---

**Update:** the following code can show more insight:

```
-(void) dropAnimate:(UIGestureRecognizer *) g {

    int n = arc4random() % 10000;
    int y = 501 + arc4random() % 200;
    NSLog(@"y is %i", y);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, y, 10, 10)];
    label.text = @"x";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 

                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"n is %i", n);
                         self.circleView.center = CGPointMake(100, y);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"n is %i", n);
                         NSLog(@"finished is %i   y is %i", finished, y);
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
                             self.circleView.center = CGPointMake(250, y);
                         }
                          ];

                     }

     ];
    NSLog(@"finished the method call");

}
```

In addition to @Kai's answer below, it seems that there is a rule to new animation for the same UIView object when there is already an animation going on: the old animation will finish its effect immediately, and the new animation is run, but then next the old animation's `completion` is called with `NO`, and now a 3rd animation is started, which causes animation 2 to finish the effect, but next its `completion` block is called, with a `NO`, and it causes animation 3 to take effect immediately...  and we see animation 4 running for 3 seconds.

The above sample code can be tried... and to simplify it, just remove the `completion` block, and then try it, and it confirms to the rule that says: if we start a new animation on the same object, the old animation takes effect immediately, and the new animation is run...

And with the `completion` block, it can get quite complicated if the `completion` block starts yet another animation...

So I think a finally thing is: does any docs or spec specify this behavior?

Comment: that's strange, in apple doc for UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: we can read: During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.)

Comment: @meronix it's described by 動靜能量, that the animation is triggered by a view which is not animated itself, so it works like apple says (if it's iOS 5)

Comment: @kay: sorry , you're right, i didn't realized he wrote that user tapped a "main view"... so no mystery at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is the following:

Your first trigger sets the `center` to `(100,300)` and than animates the view (note that the `center property` changes before you actually see it!). Your second trigger returns immediately (calls `completion` with `YES`), because there is nothing to animate (the property's already been set to the very same value before) and resets the `center` and by that forces the first animation (still running) to stop with NO, because the `circleview` is teared out from it's disired animation by getting a new `center` (note that the 2nd trigger does not disturb the 1st animation before calling `completion`, because the `circleview`'s `center property` is not changed).

Comment: if I don't tap on the main view, then it will animate for 3 seconds, and then print out the NSLog statement for TRUE... are you saying it always print out immediately with TRUE?

Comment: If you trigger the animation with a tap on the main view, your code set the value of the center and then starts the first part of the chained animation (3 sec). If nothing comes in between during animation (meaning no other thread changes the circle view) it prints TRUE after 3 sec, because the animation ran completely. But if the circle view is changed during the animation, completion is called with FALSE. Moreover, if you don't really change something on a view in an animation block, the completion block is called immediately with TRUE, because there's nothing to animate. If you combine ....

Comment: ... this you see exactly what happens when you trigger your animation twice within 3 sec. 1st trigger calls completion block with FALSE _after_ the 2nd trigger called it with TRUE.

Comment: but I see a TRUE first, and then FALSE

Comment: as I said. 2nd trigger calls completion block _first_ .

Comment: hm, now I understand what you mean by trigger... it means calling of `animateWithDuration`?  Then each time, the call to `animateWithDuration` returns immediately, not just the second time... and what do you mean by "resets the center"?  So I think you mean, the first time, the method sets the center to (100,300), the second time, it also sets it to (100,300) and ... the animation cannot be to the same center for 3 seconds... (it is strange, since if the system cannot draw a line from (100,100) to (100,100) because it is the same point, then it is weird, just like this animation)... [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] it seems that the second call to `animateWithDuration`, there is a rule: the first animation is canceled, and the new animation also will take place not for the duration, but immediately (please see update in original question for the new code that shows it)...